# SSH into NAT'd servers on the same public IP address

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris, ssh-keys

I am trying to SSH from in office X to a few Linux boxes in office Y. The Linux boxes in office Y are behind NAT and each run on their own ports. I can successfully reach all of them through SSH, but I cannot authenticate.

I was able to SSH into the first box, but when I got to the second it said:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
[edited out fingerprint]
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
```

My understanding is that it is expecting to see the same key from that public IP address, but it is seeing a different one because it's a different SSH server.

How can I fix it so it creates/accepts a different key from each server behind that same IP address?

[image]

Comment: +1 for hand drawn cloud.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The hostname or IP address is being stored as a hash (or in plain text depending on options and version defaults) in your `known_hosts` file. The easiest workaround is to add an entry for each host to DNS or [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) (ugh!) file with the same IP (WAN) address such as in `/etc/hosts`:

```
your.wan.ip.address      servera serverb
```

and then `ssh` by hostname and port.

Answer (score 22):

There are a few ways of fixing this:

1. You can disable host key checking for this particular host. In your `ssh_config` file (`~/.ssh/config`), put something like:

   ```
   Host remote.host.name
   UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
   StrictHostkeyChecking no
   ```

   This configures `ssh` to never store host keys for `remote.host.name`, but the downside is that now you are open to man-in-the-middle attacks (because you are blindly accepting host keys you can't tell if the remote host key has changed).
2. You can use a similar technique to simply give each a host a unique `known_hosts` file:

   ```
   Host hosta
   Port 10098
   Hostname remote.host.name
   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts_hosta

   Host hostb
   Port 10099
   Hostname remote.host.name
   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts_hostb
   ```

   You will then connect to these hosts with `ssh hosta` or `ssh hostb`, and `ssh` will take the actual hostname and port from the conciguration file.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  If I use the dns/host-file technique, does the same risk of man-in-middle attacks exists?  I would assume not, but just confirming.

Comment: No, modifying the `/etc/hosts` file will also work.  I like this better because (a) it doesn't require escalated privileges and (b) it means you don't need to specify port numbers on the command line.

Comment: Name resolution (hosts or DNS) will still be required in both of these solutions in order to associate hosta and hostb with the WAN IP address.  But both are excellent suggestions I was too lazy to type in LOL  Edit: Just noticed the Hostname in there - scratch that about name resolution.

Comment: @larsks Confused at "it means you don't need to specify port numbers on the command line."  Are you referring to the DNS/Host-File solution?  Wouldn't this still require me to specify the port?

Comment: @CopyRunStart:  you don't need to specify the port on the command line because it is already specified in your `~/.ssh/config` (a different port for each of `hosta` `hostb`) as described in larsks' answer.  Likewise you can specify different usernames, keys, etc. in this config-file for the different hosts so all you have to do on the command line is `ssh hosta` or `ssh hostb`

Comment: If I could upvote ~/.ssh/config twice, I would.  Fiddling with /etc/hosts is bound to cause other troubleshooting problems down the road.

Comment: This is a much better solution, IMO, than modifying /etc/hosts.  As a minor quibble, I'd use the `HostKeyAlias` directive rather than splitting out the known hosts to different files. e.g `HostKeyAlias hosta`

Answer (score 8):

You don't say which version of Solaris (and, more importantly, SSH) you're using, but sufficiently up-to-date versions of OpenSSH have addressed this problem.

Here are two entries from my `known_hosts` file, which have the same IP address but different port numbers (one is the implicit 22); as you can see the stored keys are not the same.

```
[10.69.55.47]:2222 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAo+zenWwhFWAa/exdxbm3A3htDFGwFVjFlHLO83AfOaloBbBrr6whmLeDqVPBSwI/yrePClpahLUMYE6qGBFCbbOYiQkMDwacNFfxvxd6oCMDDqZH6NWGiBCt0b2M6YKYhYCw6z8n0yvlLk1eTdpp2OpjbfwAIe4eBkWyKNZY9+17VtzARqGR9tgHC8Dh7HBApDR8wooc+XzY6FhD2b21meIt8r8bjfBIu5t6eQgDHh/TzUT1rGH6W0HeUJxpDnpud5Af1ygMEQFrGrzHi5HKtg+K6HFBggMF8t6p2Dz8oMds5pi6IuPlVi3UvO1X7mMJ9pP7ByMQqiVrQ9wtAbC2QQ==
10.69.55.47 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA1clJ6vp8NDy7D9YVgAKQQzERfx3scR0c0027yOYGGpeLg+nW+x8mJk1ia9GouUTDME+NP2YDVZUEDog9rtTJvuLd22ZxfoC8LGboyBsmlhOVxdSCxmA/+blPCp1pyocr8pXyXjSkb/qQKKQMRoAU7qKKHPfI5Vugj04l6WbW2rJQTqFD/Lguc8AAUOE6K4DNhETOH2gOnwq6xi0vutDmeUKSqEvM/PQFZSlOL4dFDYO5jAUjvgm6yGHP3LlS9fmCzayJgGgLSnNz0nlcd94Pa1Cd441cCAZHFDvDPniawEafH9ok4Mmew0UGopQGUGbfb5+8g8YphLW6aLdrvnZbAw==
```

I don't know which version of OpenSSH introduced this, but I'm running

```
[me@risby fin]$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment to @larsks answer, I think using `~/.ssh/config` entries is much better than modifying /etc/hosts, though I would use the `HostKeyAlias` rather than splitting out the known hosts to different files. e.g:

```
Host hosta
Port 10098
Hostname remote.host.name
HostKeyAlias hosta
```

And similarly for `hostb`